# SQL: Sort rows based on attribute order

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

I want to sort an the value of an attribute (called `position`) to the row number of another attribute's ordering.

Example: If I have the following attributes: position, points
I'd like to order the table by points (descending), then assign `position` the ordered row numbers ex.

```
Position --- Points

1 ------------ 99

2 ------------ 97

3 ------------ 81

etc..
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You will find that you will have a better
experience if you take moment to take the [Stack Overflow
tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). You can also read about asking a [good
question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

If you follow the norms of the Stack Overflow community and approach it with an attitude of helping others too, it will serve you well.

Comment: welcome!. in mathematics, the "number of an attribute's ordering" is simply called the "rank" of that attribute. You want to sort the entries by the points ranking. There's one example here on MySQL: `https://fellowtuts.com/mysql/query-to-obtain-rank-function-in-mysql/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that using window functions row_number()

Since the OP wants to update the records

```
with data
  as (
    select row_number() over(order by points desc) as rnk_position
           ,position
           ,points
      from leagueParticipantView /* Is this a view or a table*/
     where leagueName LIKE &leagueName
     )
update data
   set position = rnk_position
```

Comment: I tried that already, however it complains that it returns more than one row for the update statement.

Comment: UPDATE leagueParticipantView SET
    position =(SELECT RANK() OVER (ORDER BY points DESC))
    WHERE leagueName LIKE &amp;leagueName 


Note: leagueName is a parameter to a procedure

Comment: Couple of points, you are updating a view/ or do you want to update the table?. It helps if you can post the create table statements for the table you wish to update

Comment: As far as I know, a view is linked to a table where as if I do any operation on the view, it'll do it on the table also. Am I wrong?

Comment: yes unless it is a complex view with many joins or dblinks and some restrictive conditions

Answer (score 0):

Do you simply want `row_number()` or `rank()`?

```
select row_number() over (order by points desc) as position, points
from t
order by position;
```

Comment: I tried that already, however it complains that it returns more than one row for the update statement.

Answer (score 0):

To get the rank or position as your need you can simply use the RANK() function as shown below:

```
create table #MyTable (Position int,  Points int)
insert into #MyTable values (0, 99),(0, 97),(0, 89)

SELECT #MyTable.Points,  RANK ()  OVER( ORDER BY Points desc) AS Position
FROM #MyTable
```

The output will be as shown below

```
Points  Position
99      1
97      2
89      3
```

You can use it in update with inner join with original table and table with rank function as shown below.

```
UPDATE A    
  SET A.Position = B.Position
from #MyTable A
  INNER JOIN (SELECT #MyTable.Points,  RANK ()  OVER( ORDER BY Points desc) AS Position
FROM #MyTable) B ON A.Points = B.Points
```

After updating you can get the updated position as shown below using select statement

```
SELECT * FROM #MyTable

Position    Points
1           99
2           97
3           89
drop table #MyTable.
```

Hope this will help you.